# Difference (in seconds) between 2 UNIX dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I have an Unix date.
For example: 1482851624
And I want to get the difference in seconds from the actual time (in PHP).

I've tried many things without success.

Any idea?

Comment: where is your try? :-D

Comment: `abs(time()-1482851624)` gets the difference in seconds, then format it as you'd like